# How to debug Android App and Google-App-Engine projects simultaneously with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, google-app-engine

Android App is running in device.
Google-app-engine project running locally on development machine.
Normal Eclipse debugging works fine with either project with a single instance of Eclipse running for that project. But if I have 2 instances of Eclipse running (one for each project), then the Android App never finishes loading when attempting to launch via Eclipse debugger. Wondering if maybe both projects were in the same workspace if I could debug both simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Android App project and the Appengine projects need to be in the same workspace and then you can debug both simultaneously, no problem.

Presumably your Andriod app project is a client of the appengine project, and you would like to communicate between the two. If the Android app is being debugged in an Android Virtual Device (AVD) on your development machine then you should use localhost:8888 to connect to the appengine servlet from the android app. (I haven't actually tested this, but seems clear it is supposed to work that way).

But if debugging the Android app by running on a physical device which is on same subnet as development machine, then in the Run Configurations dialog (Eclipse Run/Run Configuration menu), add "--address=192.168.1.103" to Program Arguments under the (x)- Arguments tab. (but change 192.168.1.103 to whatever your development machine's IP address is on the local network). I am happy to report that this works, and is quite the slick setup for debugging the android and appengine apps together.

Comment: when I did that I keep getting:  java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 404